# How to land cleanly in Steep?

Tags: steep

Most of my jumps with snowboard and skis land harshly (the rider stumbles and the game's g-force meter spikes). Is there anything I can do to ensure a clean landing?

About jumps:

> - prepare the jump with the Right Trigger and let it
>     go exactly before the jump
> - When in air you can perform all kinds of rotations -- in this case you need to use the Sticks’ axis on your controller (Up, Down, left,
>     Right or Diagonal).
> - if you want to grab your board in the air, you need to use the Left Trigger for your left hand and the Right Trigger for your
>     right one
> - while grabbing the board you can rotate the Right Stick and add even more style to your tricks.

http://www.gameskinny.com/cy9fx/steep-beginners-guide-tips-and-tricks-for-conquering-the-slopes

Comment: Please don't remove the game name from the title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170056/339050

Comment: It's not necessary but the question could be ambiguous because of that. I concur that it wasn't a necessary edit on @Vemonus part. It's actually encouraged to put the name in the title with this sort of questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Steep there are a few things that can help you get cleaner landings when getting air.

The first and most important thing to know is that when you let go of your grabs helps with your landing. If you hold your grab until you almost hit the ground you will have a better chance of having a clean landing than if you let go of your grab mid jump. This is because of the falling animation that your character will perform when jumping a long distance. If you get this animation to occur you will most likely have a harsher landing.

Also it is of course important to make sure when you are going in for your landing you try and get your board as close to parallel to the ground as possible. The farther you are away from having your board in a parallel position to the ground the higher the chance of you taking a harsh landing and losing G's on your gauge.

The last and probably most obvious tip for better landings, don't jump off cliffs or land on rocks. I say this should be obvious if you since jumping 500 feet to the ground or landing on some rocky patch on a mountain is never going to give you a smooth landing. You might get lucky if you hold your board until you nearly land, make your board parallel to the ground, and land on snow after a large jump, but massive jumps are extremely difficult to perform cleanly so don't expect them that often. Landing on rocks of course is bad and pretty much always a harsh landing, you may be able to squeeze out a clean landing every once and awhile but don't bet on it.

Hope these tips help.

Answer (score -4):

Let go of the left stick so you can land “cleaner” but it mostly depends on the angle of the board and the ground below you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything that the other answer doesn't have.